# Make a bash script to output STDOUT & STDERR to a file

Tags: bash, output

I am searching a way to redirect every output of a bash script to a log file, but I want it inside the script.

I don't way something like myScript.sh > logfile

I would like some bash commands that I can insert a the start of the script.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just place this line on top of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec &> out.log

# rest of your script
```

This will redirect all the STDOUT and STDERR from your script to a file `out.log`, there is not need to use redirection from every command thereafter.

Comment: Exactly what I was searching ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) also for a quick redirect-anything guide.